# Vue props with @emit

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, emit, vue-props

I am not using a prop with @emit in the correct way but I don't know how to fix it. I need to know a non-global registration way of doing this correctly (I am completely new to Vue by the way)..

Here is my html in file `parent.vue`:

```
<deleteLayoutDialog v-if"showDeleteLayoutDialog"
    :layout-name="dialogNameToDelete
    @confirm="removeLayout(layout-name)"
    @cancel="setShowDeleteLayoutDialog(false)"/>
```

Here is a file `child.vue` where `deleteLayoutDialog`'s prop and @emit are defined:

```
// html
// <script>
// import { //sth } from 'files'
// @Component({ // components })
export default class DeleteLayoutDialog extends Vue {
    @Prop({required: true, type: String})
    public readonly layoutName: string;

    @Emit()
    public confirm(layoutName: string) {
        // do something
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is my javascript (inside `parent.vue`) where `columnLayoutName` appears to have a `NaN` value (in chrome dev tool)

```
public removeLayout(columnLayoutName: string) {
    if (this.columnLayout.name === columnLayoutName) {
        // (this.columnLayout is defined somewhere in this code)
        // do something...
    }
}
```

How should I change my `html` and `removeLayout` so that I am using prop properly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `removeLayout` instead of passing it as an argument.

```
@confirm="removeLayout(layout-name)"
```

You are trying to do a subtraction between `layout` and `name`, which are probably undefined, so you get `NaN`.

Just pass the reference

```
@confirm="removeLayout"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I agree that `@confirm="removeLayout"` is the way to go, but then I don't know how to use the prop in `removeLayout` function. Should I call the prop `layoutName` in `removeLayout` function? Or `this.layoutName`... I am not sure..

Comment: File where html and `removeLayout` is written is a parent of the file where prop and `@emit` are defined (I included this info in my question). I think that is why `this.layoutName` or `layoutName` is not working.  `deleteLayoutDialog.layoutName` is not working either. Do you have any suggestion on what I should do?

Comment: Aa, ok. Then you should just expect that as a param in your method.